# What is aws sftp password for open ssh login

Tags: ssh, sftp, amazon-web-services

I run

```
sftp -i privatekeyfile sftp_user@MY_ENDPOINT
```

and am asked for the password for my endpoint

```
sftp_user@MY_ENDPOINT's password:
```

What password am I supposed to supply here ?

Others have mentioned using my ssh password but I am denied access with ""

I generated my key file with  `ssh-keygen -P "" keyname`

For context, I want to setup an ftp server with access to S3 in order to share data with external customers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no password for the user. The service is using your key to authenticate.

You need to make sure the role you are using has the trust relationship to `transfer.amazonaws.com`. It should look like:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "transfer.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you mean there is no passeord to enter at the password prompt on the terminal and that I should just press enter?

Comment: You will not get any password prompt if you set correctly the role associated with your sftp (and your key is not protected with a password)

Comment: Ok, thank you, confirmed that adding transfer.amazonaws.com trust relationship resolves my issue

Comment: Kindly mark the answer